# How to implement multivalued functions when using np.linspace?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multivalued function, which I'd like to use in conjunction with np.linspace. I'm getting a Value Error whenever the function has an if/else condition in it.

I expected that applying a function f to a np.linspace is akin to mapping as in the following MWE:

```
def f(n):
    if n < 3 or n > 5:
        return 0
    else:
        return n

a = list(range(0, 11))
print(a)
print(list(map(f, a)))

b = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
print(b)
print(f(b))
```

This works fine for a regular list, but fails for np.linspace with the error

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

It would appear I'm mistaken and that np.linspace for whatever reason wants to check if every element of the array satisfies a condition. I don't want to use any() or all(), as that's not what I want to do. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `linspace` specifically. This is how `numpy` arrays work. The output of a comparison operator is another array. The `or` of two arrays is not very useful. This may help: https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a mask, for example:

```
b = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
mask = np.logical_or(b < 3, b > 5)
b[mask] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of accomplishing this task in a vectorized manner:

#### Use `np.where`

```
def f1(n):
    return np.where((n < 3) | (n > 5), 0, n)

b = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
f1(b)
```

---

#### Use multiplication:

```
def f2(n):
    return n*(n >= 3)*(n <= 5)
f2(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some have taken the MWE function too literally - I was trying to implement a bit more complex multivalued mathematical function, and their approach would have been a pain to adapt to that. Unfortunately the learning curve to do it properly was too steep for me for something that was a one time thing.

If you're willing to (very likely) take a slight hit to performance, this can be solved easily with list comprehensions:

```
def f(n):
# Where this can be an arbitrarily complex function
if n < 3 or n > 5:
    return 0
else:
    return n

b = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
c = np.array([f(i) for i in b])
```

I haven't seen any serious performance issues with this using >10^6 points, especially since I ended up `@njit`-ing `f(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is writen with single numbers in mind, comparing `n` to 3 or 5:

```
In [129]: def f(n):
     ...:     if n < 3 or n > 5:
     ...:         return 0
     ...:     else:
     ...:         return n
     ...:         

In [130]: f(1), f(4)
Out[130]: (0, 4)
```

Python has a number of `generators` which setup a calculation or iteration, but don't actually perform it.  You have to wrap them in `list` (or some `for` loop) to populate them:

```
In [131]: range(1,5)
Out[131]: range(1, 5)

In [133]: a=list(range(1,5)); a
Out[133]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You can't give your function a list:

```
In [134]: f(a)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[134], line 1
----> 1 f(a)

Cell In[129], line 2, in f(n)
      1 def f(n):
----> 2     if n < 3 or n > 5:
      3         return 0
      4     else:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

In other words `[1,2,3,4]<3` does not work.

`map` is another `generator`, which requires the list:

```
In [135]: map(f, a)
Out[135]: <map at 0x1e01f85aa40>

In [136]: list(map(f, a))
Out[136]: [0, 0, 3, 4]
```

Generators caan be strung together, without converting each intermediate step into a list:

```
In [137]: list(map(f, range(1,5)))
Out[137]: [0, 0, 3, 4]
```

### numpy

`numpy` has functions like `linspace` and `arange` that make numpy arrays.  It does not have 'generators'.

```
In [143]: b=np.linspace(1,5,5); b
Out[143]: array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
```

That array can be turned into a list:

```
In [144]: b.tolist()
Out[144]: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

and passed though the list/map:

```
In [145]: list(map(f, b.tolist()))
Out[145]: [0, 0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

In fact the array elements can be 'mapped' to your function:

```
In [146]: list(map(f, b))
Out[146]: [0, 0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

But as you found your function cannot work on an array.  It's a different error than with lists.

The array can be compared to a number:

```
In [149]: b<3
Out[149]: array([ True,  True, False, False, False])
```

In fact most math operators work with arrays - addition, equality, power, etc.  That's one of big benefits of arrays over lists.

But an `if` expression (and `or`) requires a single true/false, not an array as in [149].  That's why you get the ambiguity error.

boolean tests can be combined (the () are important):

```
In [152]: ((b<3) | (b>5))
Out[152]: array([ True,  True, False, False, False])
```

and as other showed can be used as a multivalued mask to work like your `f`.  `np.where` is one convenient tool for that, but not the only one.

```
In [155]: np.where(((b<3) | (b>5)),0,b)
Out[155]: array([0., 0., 3., 4., 5.])
```

Numpy arrays do have kind of 'map' iteration, but it's built into the array methods and operators.  Mostly it's in compiled code, and relatively fast, especially for large arrays.  But there is a significant learning curve.  You can't effectively just subtitute arrays for lists, or expect arrays to behave like your `map(f...)`.